# Firestore Security Rules get() call on list operation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having some trouble finding the right Firestore security rules to match my use case.

The collection type is called Party. There are subcollections that are mostly irrelevant. Here's an example top-level record:

```json
{
  partyName: "Foo",
  members: {
    uid123: {
      member: true
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following simplified security rules:

```json
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read, write: if false;
    
    match /parties/{partyId} {
      // Define a helper
      function isPartyMember() {
        return request.auth != null && 
            get(/databases/$(database)/documents/parties/$(partyId))
                .data.get(['members', request.auth.uid, 'member'], false) == true;
      }

      // Top level collection
      allow read, write: if isPartyMember();

      // Subcollection prevents using "resource" variable in shared helper.
      match /subcollection/{subId} {
        allow read: if isPartyMember();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am issuing the following query on web v9:

```js
const resp = await getDocs(
  query(
    collection(this.firestore, "parties"),
    where(`members.${this.auth.currentUser.uid}.member`, "==", true)
  )
);
```

As far as I can tell, I am following the rules:

- The security rules exactly match the query.
- The function has access to the `partyId` variable.
- This should only query for valid documents.

Notes:

- When I test the read rules via Rules Playground, it seems to work as I'd expect.
- Replacing the full `get(...)` call with `resource` actually works (!), but I can't do this because of the subcollection. It has to be an explicit reference.

Unfortunately, when I run the query I get Missing or insufficient permissions. What am I missing? Can you not secure docs with a `get()` operation in a `list` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For top level collections, you don't have to use `get()` to read data of current document. Try refactoring the rules as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read, write: if false;
    
    match /parties/{partyId} {
      // Define a helper
      function isPartyMember() {
        return request.auth != null && 
            get(/databases/$(database)/documents/parties/$(partyId))
                .data.get(['members', request.auth.uid, 'member'], false) == true;
      }

      // Top level collection
      // Use resource.data instead of get();
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.get(['members', request.auth.uid, 'member'], false) == true;
      
      // Subcollection prevents using "resource" variable in shared helper.
      match /subcollection/{subId} {
        allow read: if isPartyMember();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not totally sure about this behaviour but using `resource.data` instead of `get()` for top level collection should work.

From what I can see, if you attempt to use `get()` to get data of document being evaluated in a `list` operation, the rule fails (though it works when you are fetching a single document by ID). For example:

```
match /subcollection/{subId} {
  // Rule fails
  allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/parties/$(partyId)/subcollection/$(subId)).data.field == 'value';

  // Rule passes
  allow read: if resource.data.field == 'value';

  // Rule passes
  allow read: if isPartyMember(); // reads parent document
}
```

Comment: I've sent a support ticket to get any confirmations on what I think could be the reason. Will keep this one updated.

Comment: Interesting. Can you only not use get on the document being evaluated in a list? (ie for listing /parties/foo/subcollecton, can I still use the get there?)

Comment: @mdierker list as in? Each document is evaluated individually so if you are querying multiple documents from a collection/sub-collection then the rule is checked again every document matching your query separately.

Comment: `list` as in the `allow list` [rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

Update: I tested it... splitting the rules and using `resource` instead when checking for `list` works. `allow list: if resource.data.foo` and `allow get: if isPartyMember()`. Continuing to use `get()` works for subcollections too.

This... seems like a bug? `get()` operations work for getting a single document + for `list` and `get` on a party's subcollections, but not for `list` on a document itself?